# Enable authorization in express-gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, express-gateway

I'm having a bit of an issue enabling authorization in express-gateway.

Based on the docs, Express Gateway is designed to apply policies to specific endpoints using its configuration files (gateway-config.yml), and that's what I'd like to avoid.

I'd like to perform global authentication or authorization for all requests before they reach Express Gateway's policies, i.e. instead of adding a **jwt** policy to all my pipelines like this:

```
pipelines:
  testing:
    apiEndpoints:
      - testing
    policies:
      - jwt:
          - action:
              secretOrPublicKeyFile: certs/key.pem
```

I would like to intercept all the requests before they reach the gateway, authorize/authenticate, and then forward the request to the gateway for handling the routing to the correct endpoint.

I thought of using Express to handle all the incoming traffic, route the requests to Passport middleware for authentication/authorization, and upon successful authentication/authorization, forward the request to express-gateway.

**passport-config.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

const secretKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'certs', 'key.pem');
const secretKey = fs.readFileSync(secretKeyPath, 'utf-8');

const jwtOptions = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: secretKey,
};

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (payload, done) => {
    const user = payload.user;

    if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
    } else {
        return done(null, false);
    }
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

**middleware.js**

```
const passport = require('./passport-config');

function authenticationMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: user });
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })(req, res, next);
}

module.exports = authenticationMiddleware;
```

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const gateway = require('express-gateway');
const express = require('express');
const authenticationMiddleware = require('./middleware/auth-middleware');

gateway()
    .load(path.join(__dirname, 'config'))
    .run();

const app = express();

app.use(require('./middleware/passport-config').initialize());

app.use(authenticationMiddleware);

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```

So with the above setup, the requests are going to Express, and Passport is successfully authorizing the requests, but **I'm not sure how to send the request through to the gateway after Passport has successfully authorized the request.**

**Is there a better way of doing this? it looks a bit overkill.**